# export csv from aws rds to other aws account s3 butcket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I currently have aws account A and B. I have an RDS on A and an S3 bucket on B. I tried using query_export_to_s3 to export a csv file however, account B is receiving the file but not able to open it due to encryption added with A key. I created a kms key from B and added to A. Is there a way for me to run the query_export_to_s3 specifying to use the B key to encrypt the file instead of A's key? Due to security, I am unable to create a kms key and added to B. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with access to a KMS key and not simply that, even though the object is in account B's bucket, it is still owned by account A.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod I am new to aws, this could definetely be the case! If it is, what do you recommend I can do to give ownership to account B s3 bucket?

Comment: Use [S3 Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) to control who owns objects uploaded to an S3 bucket. For new buckets, Bucket owner enforced is the default.

Comment: And see the docs for [Allowing users in other accounts to use a KMS key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying-external-accounts.html), if you actually want the object to remain encrypted with an account A KMS key. Or KMS decrypt the data in account A and then upload it to account B, encrypting with an account B KMS key.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod, this is a new bucket that we created and we are using the  Bucket owner enforced. We have also created a kms key in B and added to A is there a way to use this key to encrypt?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, do you know how I can use B KMS key to encrypt when uploading to B's S3 bucket? could I add it to the query query_export_to_s3?

Comment: The [Exporting data from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-examples) page suggests that "Cross-account export to Amazon S3 isn't supported." Are you using PostgreSQL? Are you actually seeing the export appear in account B's bucket?

Comment: @jarmod yes I have been able to successfully export a file into the s3 bucket. The issue is we are not able to open the file due to the key being form account A and not B

Comment: Haven't done this before but if you need to do it in one step then I'd investigate if the kms_text parameter that you supply to query_export_to_s3 can be the key of a KMS key in account B. And also ensure that the IAM role that you attach to the RDS instance has permissions on the account B bucket and the account B KMS key. I don't know if this will work. If it doesn't, you might have to export to a bucket in account A, then move with decrypt/re-encrypt to a bucket account B.